# Tomcat with SignalR

Tags: signals

I have an Asp.Net solution (Fx 4.5) that uses SignalR to push data syncs to connected clients. It works well and is easy to implement (on Windows/OWIN).

I have been asked about using a Tomcat Webserver. I know Tomcat can be configured for ASP.Net applications, BUT has anyone tried to deploy any SignalR module?